# Loading JNI libraries from JRuby script started from Java fails

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jruby

I want to load Apple's mDNS library for use in a JRuby application. The JRuby app starts up as a Java process, that then evaluates the Ruby script.

Here's the Java code for a minimal repro case, which just grabs the Ruby script & evals it:

```
package mdnsscratch;

import com.apple.dnssd.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jruby.Ruby;
import org.jruby.RubyInstanceConfig;
import org.jruby.RubyRuntimeAdapter;
import org.jruby.javasupport.JavaEmbedUtils;
import org.jruby.runtime.builtin.IRubyObject;

public final class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws DNSSDException, IOException {
    final Main m = new Main();
    final byte[] buffy = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(args[0]));
    m.run(new String(buffy));
  }

  private void run(final String cmd) {
    //System.out.println("About to eval: "+ cmd);
    // Get a ruby runtime
    final RubyInstanceConfig rubyConfig = new RubyInstanceConfig();
    rubyConfig.setExternalEncoding("UTF-8");
    rubyConfig.setInternalEncoding("UTF-8");

    final Ruby runtime = JavaEmbedUtils.initialize(new ArrayList(), rubyConfig);
    final RubyRuntimeAdapter rubyEvaluater = JavaEmbedUtils.newRuntimeAdapter();

    final IRubyObject iro = rubyEvaluater.eval(runtime, cmd);
    System.out.println(iro.toString());
  }
}
```

and here's a minimal Ruby script to repro the problem:

```
require 'java'
require 'lib/dns_sd.jar'

# Listener
class RegistrarListener
  def recordRegistered(record, flags)
  end
  def operationFailed(service, errorCode)
    puts "WARNING: mDNS operation failed"
  end
end

# Registrar
puts "About to register"
DNSSD = Java::ComAppleDnssd::DNSSD
@@registrar = DNSSD.createRecordRegistrar(RegistrarListener.new)
puts "Done registering"
```

The mDNS library has a lot of native code it it, so I have the dns_sd.jar and the .dylib (I'm on a Mac) in lib/. Direct evaluation with JRuby works fine:

```
$ jruby -J-Djava.library.path=lib test_mdns.rb
About to register
Done registering
```

But using the Java wrapper fails:

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=lib -cp target/classes:lib/dns_sd.jar:/opt/jruby/lib/jruby.jar mdnsscratch.Main test_mdns.rb
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- lib/dns_sd
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071)
    at RUBY.(root)(<script>:4)
```

It almost seems as though JRuby, when called from the Java wrapper, can't see the JNI part of the mDNS library.

Can anyone help? Happy to respond to comments & give extra information as needed.

OK, so this is the Java command that actually gets run by JRuby:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/java8/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx500m 
-Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/opt/jruby-1.7.17/lib/jni 
-Djava.library.path=lib -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/jruby-1.7.17/lib/jruby.jar 
-classpath : -Djruby.home=/opt/jruby-1.7.17 
-Djruby.lib=/opt/jruby-1.7.17/lib -Djruby.script=jruby 
-Djruby.shell=/bin/sh org.jruby.Main test_mdns.rb
```

This equivalent command line:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/java8/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx500m 
-Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/opt/jruby-1.7.17/lib/jni 
-Djava.library.path=lib -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/jruby-1.7.17/lib/jruby.jar 
-classpath target/classes:lib/dns_sd.jar 
-Djruby.home=/opt/jruby-1.7.17 -Djruby.lib=/opt/jruby-1.7.17/lib 
-Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh mdnsscratch.Main test_mdns.rb
```

still gives the error. Currently looking at the JRuby source, and I see mention of a special thread-local classloader, which is interesting, especially as the JRuby invocation contains an empty classpath argument.

Comment: Just wondering...is this something that the all-Ruby dnsruby gem might be able to do for you with less hassle than Apple's mdns? Here are some links for that gem:

Github repo: https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby

Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dnsruby

Comment: Does dnsruby actually do mDNS? From a cursory scan, it appears to be a standard DNS implementation.

Comment: I think you're right, it does not do mDNS.  Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

> classes loaded from bootclasspath can only link against libraries in
>   $JAVA_HOME/bin

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4620

Comment: That doesn't explain the observed behaviour. It's java -Djava.library.path=lib -cp target/classes:lib/dns_sd.jar:/opt/jruby/lib/jruby.jar mdnsscratch.Main test_mdns.rb
that's failing, which doesn't mention the bootclasspath

Answer (score 0):

From conversations on Twitter: "JRuby launcher puts . in classpath similar to java command, but your java cmd specifies a class path so no pwd."

Adding . to the classpath fixes this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib -cp target/classes:lib/dns_sd.jar:/opt/jruby/lib/jruby.jar:. mdnsscratch.Main test_mdns.rb
About to register
Done registering
```